# get synatx error from writing javascript destructure with export function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I have a index.ts file for export libary, but I got error message like below, what's wrong overhere?, I thought it should work.

```
// components
import List from './components/List'
import Item from './components/Item'
// containers
import ListStackConatiner from './containers/ListStackConatiner'

const components = {
  List,
  Item
}

const containers = {
  ListStackConatiner
}

export {
  ...components,
  ...containers
}
```

SyntaxError: /somepath/src/index.ts: Unexpected token (17:2)(line in ...components)

Comment: Which is the line showing the error?

Comment: `export {` is the syntax for *named exports*, right? It's not exactly the same thing as an object, so maybe spreading is impossible inside it.

Comment: You can't use destructuring during export.

Comment: Is there another way to do something like this?

Comment: You could use a default export of an object instead, into which you can spread whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do destructuring inside a named export natively - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43300725/10221765) explains why. Instead, you can use `Object.assign`:

```
export default Object.assign({}, components, containers);
```

You could also destructure into another variable, then just `export` that:

```
var exportObj = {
    ...components,
    ...containers
};

export default {exportObj};
```

Comment: Sorry, how would I export that then? I'm not that good with export/import syntax.

Comment: Pretty sure a default export instead of a named export would work fine

Comment: Looks like you are trying to guess correct syntax. I don't think this is what OP wants, in any case what you have now.

Comment: I'm sorry, but above it was mentioned that `export default` would work. How should I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
export = {
  ...components,
  ...containers
}
```

instead.