# How to use javaScript file as Higher Order wrapper for other JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to ask, as in react we have HOC (Higher order components) where we pass components that modify it and then return modified Component for use

can we do same in javaScript?

for Example

```
// index1.js
// this is file where i am importing all the folder modules and exporting them

export { methodA, methodB } from './xyzAB'
export { methodC, methodD } from './xyzCD'
```

i am importing this file in another folder like this

```
import * as allMethods from './modules'

// this allows me to use this syntax
allMethods.methodA()
allMethods.methodB()
```

this is working fine, but i am looking for this kind of wrapper

```
// index2.js 
// this is another file somewhere else where i want to use index1.js exported methods

import * as allMethods from './modules/xyz'
import anotherMethod from './somewhere/xyz'

// here i want customize some of `allMethods` functions and export them as new object
//which contains modifed version of default `index1.js` methods

allMethods.methodA = allMethods.methodA( anotherMethod ) // this is example of modified as HO Method


export default allMethods
```

My Above example may seem confusing, 
why i am looking for such solution, i have set of utilities which i am trying to make them as library and use them in multiple projects,

now some of utils are dependent on main project related things, so instead of giving my utilities hard coded reference to their dependencies, 
i want to pass different dependencies for different methods through my higher order method or configuration file, 
so that each new project pass its dependent utilities from their config or higher order wrapper file as example shown above

I hope i was able to clear my question,

Few things which i tried, 
i tried importing all modules in file which i count as wrapper file
in that if i try to use any module that returns webpack error as undefined method, due to methods not loaded fully until few seconds, i tried setTimeOut, that works fine, but this is not valid way of managing thing,

then i tried some async way, i used dynamic `import()` which returns promise, i used async/await syntax, and also used .then syntax but couldn't extract data and save it as variable (i may be doing something wrong at this step but i was totally failed) but this was only available with in promise or async await scope,

there were also other steps tried,

i am hoping i could  find some neater syntax like below

```
import * as F from '../../core/lib/functions'
import { getModel } from '../entities'

F.getKeys = F.getKeys( getModel )


export default F
```

any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is some sort of currying or factory-like pattern.

There is no such thing as higher order modules but since JavaScript support higher order functions that is what you should use.

Just as a reminder, a higher order component is any component that takes a component as a parameter and returns another component. Similarly (simplified) a higher order function is one that takes a function as a parameter and returns a new function. (in reality all React components are more or less functions so thus why we are able to have higher order components).

The key thing is that you need to call a higher order function, not just import it (since again, there is no such thing as a higher order module). But this ties well into your idea of dependency injection.

I think, what you want is something like this in your utilities:

```
function a(dependency1, arg1, arg2) {}

function b(dependency2, arg1, arg2) {}

function createUtils(dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
       a: a.bind(null, dependency1), 
       b: b.bind(null, dependency2) 
  } 
}
```

This allows you to customize per project what dependency 1 and 2 are and the details for how they work (with some common interface). With the binding you don't have to pass that dependency in with every call to a function.

Then in one of your projects you'd set them up something like this:

```
import { createUtils} from 'utils';
import { dependency1, dependency2 } from 'somewhere' ;

const { a, b } = createUtils(dependency1, dependency2)

export { a, b };
```

You're not really doing any higher order function stuff, like I said this is more like a factory/dependency injection thing. Though `bind` is a higher order function (it takes the function it's called in and returns a new function with some arguments bound).

You can put place in createUtils for general modifications through another parameter with options. Or you can export smaller "factories" for each method that you want to be able to modify.

With that in mind you might to only export the raw functions from utils and use `bind` in your module setup code to bind the dependencies. I think `bind` is what you are missing. As well as that you have to create new functions to export, rather than modifying the imported functions. That also means that your imports in the rest of your code will come only from within your own module, not from the utils module.

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer,
actually i am having function composition in my utilities
here is example of one of composition  

`export function getKeys(callback) {
 return entity => callback(entity).key
}
`
in config/ or higher order file wrapper i will set callback methods for each method and assign them to new variable and then export from that
and yes after doing this i will use my current wrapper file in project to export newly modified methods
i hope this more clear my question

Comment: Is there something that is still unclear for you in how to achieve this?

Comment: can you tell me is this possible i do something like this
`import * as F from '../../core/lib/functions'
import {createModelUtils} from '../../core/lib/functions'
import { getModel } from '../entities'

const { getKeys } = createModelUtils(getModel)


export default { getKeys, ...F }
`

I want to use this same wrapper file and import it in whole project where i can use all exported methods from /core/lib/functions 

and please clear how do you intent to use this `export {a, b}`
a(null, arg1, arg2) or how this will be use after binding dependency

Comment: Using spread in exports doesn't work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300618/using-the-spread-syntax-in-javascript-es6-named-exports. How you would use `a`: `import { a } from './module/utils/'; a(arg1, arg2);`. When doing `bind` we have bound the function context (`this`) to null, and we've bound the "first" argument to dependency1. The function takes 3  arguments so you only need to provide the last 2.

Comment: Thank you milton i was able to find info about spread, i read they mentioned it is in stage 3, not implemented yet etc, and i was also able to use these exported methods, if you closely see things when i use * as F to import it takes delay and prompt variables as undefined and if i de structure seperately it works fine do you have any idea regarding that? if possible can we do few mins hangout call?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, can you share some more code, maybe in a https://pastebin.com/?

Comment: I may not be able clear my question through pastebin, if possible lets have small hangout i will share my screen, no problem i am also not good english spoke person, your answer helped me in other way, thanks for that i just wanted to ask more question is possible 
thanks again

Comment: I'm afraid that's not something I'd be comfortable with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212867/discussion-between-hanzla-habib-and-milton).