# Automatically export all properties as named exports

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm wanting to create a simple mechanism whereby I can switch out the underlying provider that I'm using to get blog entries (among other things).

You'll notice that I'm explicitly exporting `getBlogBySlug` at the end of the file. This is fine with just a few named exports, but I may end up with a whole load of these.

Is there any way to export all the properties of the `providerImplementation` as individual named exports without defining them all individually as named exports?

All of the provider implementations (blog system A and B in the code) will adhere to the same interface.

```
import * as blogSystemA from './providers/blog-system-a'
import * as blogSystemB from './providers/blog-system-b'
import { BlogProvider } from './types'

let providerImplementation: BlogProvider

if (provider === Provider.BLOG_SYSTEM_A) {
  providerImplementation = blogSystemB
} else if (provider === Provider.BLOG_SYSTEM_B) {
  providerImplementation = blogSystemB
}

export const getBlogBySlug = providerImplementation.getBlogBySlug
```

Comment: any reason you cannot  just export providerImplementation and simply use providerImplementation.someMethod afterwards ?

Comment: @ABOS - nope. I was just hoping to keep a consistent approach with other modules that I've created (which don't have multiple underlying implementations).

Comment: Found the answer to this in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43300725/15109163